# Using ClickOnce to automatically update company application with personal FTP server

Tags: c#, ftp, clickonce

This is my first Stack Overflow question so apologies if this isn't great...

I'm sure this is something either super simple I am missing or something very complex that I've gotten myself into, but I am using ClickOnce for the first time to create an automated updater for a company application I developed.

The application itself was originally written in VB but I have translated it into C#. We use this to automate a database of assets, which changes very frequently. I have been tasked to allow it to complete automated updates to keep from confusing some of the techs with uninstall/reinstalling the application weekly.

I volunteered to make an FTP server using a personal server machine I use at home. Normally this machine would be used for local networking but I've wanted to create an FTP server for some time (this is my first FTP server too).

So I went on my way, set the publish location for the build to `ftp://[IP.ADDRESS]:21/Folder/Subfolder` and the Installation folder URL to `http://[IP.ADDRESS]:21/Folder/Subfolder`

Long story short, when I try to test an update (changing only the assembly version), I am an error:

> System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading http://[IP.ADDRESS]:21/Folder/Subfolder/applciation.application did not succeed ---> System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation.

I did some research and tried adding an SSL certificate and changed the update path to `https://[IP.ADDRESS]:21/Folder/Subfolder/` then tested that. This time around, I get this error:

> System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading http://[IP.ADDRESS]:21/Folder/Subfolder/applciation.application did not succeed ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected format.

I cannot tell if this is progress or if I moved backwards here LOL. I've been jumping back and forth and going to many threads to try to figure out where this is going wrong. I'm also having a pretty tricky time finding out if this is an error with how I've set up ClickOnce or if this is an error in how I have set up FTP with IIS.

Apologies if this is not enough information, I can provide more if necessary. Also apologies if this is too much information! Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear why one would need to uninstall/re-install an app weekly or why one would need to "update" it every week - seems like poor design.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [How to: Download files with FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-download-files-with-ftp)

Comment: @user9938 It updates weekly because they change out the asset types and contracts associated with each one. The program itself updates these assets and loads them to a database. They want to change the options on it pretty frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're working for a small company and infrastructure/resources are at a premium. With that in mind I'll offer some suggestions:

1. Does your company have a network shared drive? I don't like ClickOnce, but I have deployed it to network shares in the past with success. This has the benefit of you not needing to deal with security.
2. Have you considered migrating this to a web application? Web development seemed really daunting when I was a native app developer, but with Blazor and ASP.NET Core it's become a lot more accessible. This would completely get rid of the need for updating the application.
3. Consider an alternative deployment route. ClickOnce is not incredibly well supported.

I'd be remiss if I didn't throw a red flag on security. FTP is a very old protocol and is basically insecure by design. Hosting it on your home server means that you're transmitting the app over the public internet... What would happen if someone outside your company installed the application?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Really appreciated! You are correct that the company I work for is a fairly small IT company. We do have a network drive so I might look at that as an option! But I have been wanting to do more with ASP.NET so I might play around with that idea!

Thanks!